# Laptop monitor is 1366x768 but second screen is 1080p. why?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I have an Asus K53E which has an Intel 3000 graphics chipset. Why is the laptop's resolution 1366x768, but the the second monitor it's connected to is 1080p?

Comment: Note that the reason it chose that resolution, is that it is the second monitors preferred resolution, and as Darius pointed out, your video output device is capable of supporting it. the TV can tell the computer its preference using the E-EDID protocol over HDMI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data

Answer (score 3):

Because Intel HD Graphics can support Full HD (1920 x 1080) resolution.

Actual displayed resolution will depends on:

1. Connector used between the device to the monitor (HDMI and DisplayPort have different resolution support)
2. The monitor capability

Your ASUS K53E laptop monitor only supports up to 1366x768. Your external monitor may support up to 1920x1080 (or maybe even higher).